# ffmpeg removing silence makes mp3 longer?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3

I've been using the following command to attempt to remove silent segments from an mp3 file

`ffmpeg -i "podcasts/audio1.mp3" -af silenceremove=1:0:-50dB "/tmp/pod-sil.mp3"`

For some reason the resulting mp3 is twice as log as the input mp3. It is not half as fast. There does not appear to be any duplicated audio. There is some silence, but not an hour's worth. For a given portion of the input file, you can find the same thing in the output file by going to twice the timestamp of the input file.

The files are long so I have not yet listened to them all the way through. I really have no idea where the extra length is coming from, the files seem normal.

Here is the full output from ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[mp3 @ 0x21880e0] Skipping 0 bytes of junk at 0. 
[mp3 @ 0x21880e0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from 'podcasts/audio1.mp3':
  Duration: 01:00:00.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 320 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 320 kb/s
File '/tmp/pod-sil.mp3' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, mp3, to '/tmp/pod-sil.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TSSE            : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libmp3lame
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp3 (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libmp3lame @ 0x21999e0] Trying to remove 1152 samples, but the queue is empty
size=   56253kB time=01:00:00.16 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:56253kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000439%
```

Comment: Need to see full log.

Comment: Ok. There you go.

Comment: It is longer by 35 samples, cause gapless remainder is destroyed: see https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/9755#comment:16